# Send top five list's attachment's link to someone via email

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, outlook, power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I'm trying to use MS automate to make a flow for sending top five files within their attachment link to myself via email. The file saved in a MS Sharepoint list. Every week I will manually create list's item and upload files.

The steps I have been done so far for the flow:

- Initialize an variable named link1(float type）for store attachment link
- Initialize an variable named int, set to 5 and integer type
- Execute until.condition:when int less or equal, create item (title: int), a decrease variable for make "int" 's value decrease 1 for every execution.

Up till now, I am facing my first question. Above steps I aim to create five new list's items in my Sharepoint automatically, then I could upload my files manually. The problem is after ran the flow, it only create one file in my Sharepoint named int(which is 5). How could I change my steps to achieve my goal?

Then I set a Sharepoint get item, set my site and my list, and ID I used int. In this step I want to make the item correspond to the one the flow created.

- Sharepoint get attachment, the ID also int
- Apply to each, use the value from last step, use AbsoluteUri assign value to the link1
- Final step: outlook send email(V2).

The problem is I am using below code to write the email, I want to get the different information(ex:title, context, information, id, attachment link) for this five files and included them in the email. For my flow now, it only shows the information for one single file, could not include other four, how to solve this problem?

```
<a href="sharepointxxxxxxx">
    <img src="//I set a border pic" border="0" width="423" height="180">
</a><BR>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-color: #9abad9; border-spacing: 0px; width: 423px;" class="tg">
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="background-color: #409cff; color: #ffffff; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; overflow: hidden; padding: 10px 5px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; word-break: normal; border: 1px solid #9abad9; width: 423px;"><strong><span style="color: #ffffff; background-color: #409cff;">//variableinsharepoint://variableinsharepoint</span></strong></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #ebf5ff; color: #444444; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; overflow: hidden; padding: 10px 5px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; word-break: normal; border: 1px solid #9abad9; width: 306.333px;"><span style="color: #444; background-color: #ebf5ff;">//variable from get item</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<style>
#customers {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#customers td, #customers th {
  border: 1px solid #9abad9;
  padding: 8px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #ebf5ff;}

#customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#customers th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #409cff;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table id="customers">
    <tbody><tr>
        <th>TYPE</th>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@{outputs('get item')?['body/OData__x5de5__x5177_/Value']}</td>
        <td><span style=\“font-size:11px\”><a href="attachment link')}">@{outputs('get item')?['body/OData__x540d__x79f0_']}</a></span></td>
        <td>@{outputs('get item')?['body/OData__x63cf__x8ff0_']}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@{outputs('get item')?['body/OData__x5de5__x5177_/Value']}</td>
        <td><span style=\“font-size:11px\”><a href="@{variables('attachment link')}">@{outputs('get item')?['body/OData__x540d__x79f0_']}</a></span></td>
        <td>@{outputs('get item')?['body/OData__x63cf__x8ff0_']}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@{outputs('get item')?['body/OData__x5de5__x5177_/Value']}</td>
        <td><span style=\“font-size:11px\”><a href="@{variables('attachment link')}">@{outputs('get item')?['body/OData__x540d__x79f0_']}</a></span></td>
        <td>@{outputs('get item)?['body/OData__x63cf__x8ff0_']}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@{outputs('get item')?['body/OData__x5de5__x5177_/Value']}</td>
        <td><span style=\“font-size:11px\”><a href="@{variables('attachment link')}">@{outputs('get item')?['body/OData__x540d__x79f0_']}</a></span></td>
        <td>@{outputs('get item)?['body/OData__x63cf__x8ff0_']}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@{outputs('get item')?['body/OData__x5de5__x5177_/Value']}</td>
        <td><span style=\“font-size:11px\”><a href="@{variables('attachment link')}">@{outputs('get item')?['body/OData__x540d__x79f0_']}</a></span></td>
        <td>@{outputs('get item)?['body/OData__x63cf__x8ff0_']}</td>
    </tr>

</tbody></table>

<iframe id="xpathCopyIframe" style="height: 0px; width: 0px;" src="./w3school.com.cn_demo_html_table_files/saved_resource.html"></iframe></body></html>
```

Comment: I don't know SharePoint or "MS automate" but AFAIK, usual approach for building HTML with data from database is to loop through a recordset and in each loop iteration pull values from record and concatenate, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36878466/need-to-loop-through-recordset-to-insert-html-table-in-outlook-email-body

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation, I still have some doubts, can you tell me?
What does an attachment link in an email mean?
If you want to get the top five email attachments, I think you can get the top five by modifying the formula in the value of Apply to every email attachments: take(triggerOutputs()?['body/attachments'], 5).

If you can, can you show a screenshot of part of your flow so we can understand your thinking more clearly?

Comment: @ChengFeng-MSFT Thx for your response. I am trying to get the link to the file from my Sharepoint and put it in my email. Once I click the textbox in my email, it will automatically download the file I put in Sharepoint. I have solved the problem and stored the value by using the array. Automate support to get multiple item values, but not support getting multiple links by single steps.  So I used 'get items' 5 times to get 5 file links. Finally, I use variables('array name')[index][name of the information needed] structure to put information inside my email.