# Add checked row in a form to email

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to

1. allow the user to select a check box field called FHPRejected a (Yes/No) field that is in a split form in MS Access.
2. click a button REJECT/EMAIL to auto select information from a field called RID and others to identify the row of information that needs to be fixed.
3. auto generate an Outlook email to preselected personnel

I created code that will call Outlook and generate a basic email.

How can I add information from the form?

Form Name: FRM_Approved
Button Name: Btn_Rejected
Field that denotes if row data is to be used: FHPRejected
Name of form check box and or form entry: FHPRejected
FHPRejected is a yes/no box
Keys or set number field: AutoRID

SQL

```
SELECT tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.RID, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.FundCenter, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.ParentOrg, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.ExtendedOrg, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.Fund, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.Reason, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.WBS, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.FundingSource, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.[AMO Packet], tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.AMO_Number, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.MissionCriticality, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.FundingCategory, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.FunctionalArea, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.ObjectClass, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.FencedName, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.FencedWBS, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.OctoberPgm, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.NovemberPgm, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.DecemberPgm, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.JanuaryPgm, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.FebruaryPgm, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.MarchPgm, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.AprilPgm, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.MayPgm, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.JunePgm, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.JulyPgm, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.AugustPgm, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.SeptemberPgm, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.Remarks, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.BC_Comments, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.BO_Comments, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.AnalystName, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.RequestDTG, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.BC_ApprovedDTG, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.Documents, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.AutoRID, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.FiscalMonth, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.TotalChange, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.CurrentYear, tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.FHPRejected
FROM tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input
WHERE (((tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input.BC_Comments) Is Null));
```

```vb
Public Function emailFHP_Program_Rejected()
'***************************************************************************************
'
' -This function generates a FHP Program Rejection email notification to recipients based on a
'  Yes/No requirement to receive the notice in the "FHP_Email" column of the "tbl_Emails".
'
'***************************************************************************************

Dim dailyMail As MailItem
Dim strEmail As String
Dim strBody As String
Dim strSubject As String
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim rs1 As Recordset
Dim grt As String

processNotice = MsgBox("Would you like to send a FHP Program Rejection Notification?", vbYesNo, "Process Notice")
If processNotice = vbYes Then
    'Call updateStatusBar("Generating email.....")
    Set dailyMail = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    SQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Emails"
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)
    'Move through Email table to gather emails to poplulate distribtion of the email.
    With rs
        If Not .EOF And Not .BOF Then
            .MoveLast
            .MoveFirst
            For i = 0 To .RecordCount - 1
                If !FHP_Email = True Then
                    strEmail = strEmail & !Email & ";"
                    .MoveNext
                Else: .MoveNext
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End With

    'Retrieve the text to use in the body of the email based on the type selected from a dropdown
    SQL1 = "SELECT * From tbl_EmailMessage"
    Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL1)
    'With grt
        If Time <= TimeValue("11:59:59 AM") Then
            grt = "Good Morning,"
        Else
            grt = "Good Afternoon,"
        End If
    'End With
    'Combine email body and subject based on message
    With rs1
        strSubject = "**FHP PROGRAM UPDATE NOTICE**"
    End With
    'Change the following email information as needed
    With dailyMail
        .Subject = strSubject
        '(Format(Now, "dd MMMM yy"))
        .To = strEmail
        '.Attachments.Add ("\\RUCKW0U9G67001\drm\PBD\DATA CALL\PAE\Daily Reports\SAG Recap\SAG " & (Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy"))) & ".xlsx"
        .Importance = olImportanceHigh
        '.Send
        .Display
        'Sets body of email equal to message type selected with daily numbers and signature block of sender
        .HTMLBody = grt & "<b> <br><br><br>FHP Program Have Been Rejected: " & " " & Time & _
          "</b><br><br>Waiting for Correction.<br><br><br>v/r," & "<br><br>Financial Operations"
    End With

ElseIf vbNo Then
    
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Do you want only one record data to be included in email? Code can pull data from record that has focus on form. Checkbox is not needed unless you want to allow selection of multiple records in which case would require looping code to build HTML table. But be aware that multiple users checking/unchecking field will conflict. Automating Outlook and building message with HTML structure is a common scenario.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need to loop through recordset to insert HTML table in Outlook email body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36878466/need-to-loop-through-recordset-to-insert-html-table-in-outlook-email-body)

Comment: Ill have to look it over more, maby it will work thanks for the response. Also to answer your question I want to pull one fields data

Comment: If you want data just from active record on form, simply reference field or control names.

Comment: June7 can you code this to be multiple selections of the field RID?

Comment: Think I already addressed that scenario in my first two comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function rejectNoticePgmFHP()

        Set dbs = CurrentDb()
        Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("QueryAppendRejectionProgram")
        'qdf.Parameters(0) = [BC_Approved]
        Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset()

With rst
  Do While Not rst.EOF
  Mailbody = Mailbody & ![RID] & " FHP Requested by " & ![AnalystName] & _
  " was REJECTED by" & ![BC_Name] & "Requested Date" & ![RequestDTG] & " Reson For Rejection as follows: " & ![Remarks] & vbCrLf
  rst.MoveNext
  Loop
End With


Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set olItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)

olItem.Display
olItem.To = "me@mymail.com"
olItem.Subject = "FHP Rejection"
olItem.Body = Mailbody

Set dbs = CurrentDb()
Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("QueryAppendRejectionProgram")
'qdf.Parameters(0) = [BC_Approved]
Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset()

strHTML = "<HTML><Body><table border='1' width='50%'><tr><th>Request Date</th><th>Submitted By</th>" & _
"<th>Department</th><th>Effective Date</th><th>Description</th></tr>"

'Initialize MailBody
Mailbody = strHTML
.Importance = olImportanceHigh

With rst
  Do While Not rst.EOF
  ' Here you append the current record to the end of the Mailbody variable.
  Mailbody = strHTML & "<tr><td>" & rst("RequestDTG") & "</td><td>" & _
        rst("AnalystName") & "</td><td>" & rst("RID") & "</td><td>" & _
        rst("BC_Name") & "</td><td>" & rst("Remarks") & "</td></tr>" & _
        vbCrLf

   rst.MoveNext
   Loop
End With


End Function
```