# Filter out duplicate email subjects and inserting a filtered table into an email

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to using VBA. I have been looking for someone trying to solve the same issue as me but haven't had any luck. Hoping I can get some help here.

I have a spreadsheet like the one pictured below and I need the macro to create emails to the addresses in column F, add the subject line in column E without creating duplicates emails for the same subjects like that ones in E4 and E5 (for clarity, I would only want to generate 1 email for each unique subject), then filter through the data to copy and paste columns A to D in the email for items with the same subject

Data Table

[image]

Currently, I have what is below. The code I found online works and generates multiple emails but will create an email for each line which causes the duplicate problem I am looking to get solved. It also doesn't include the step that filters the data to copy and paste columns A:D in my email (very unsure how to do that).

My r is set = 6 because on my personal spreadsheet that is where the data starts, the body is set up the same way where what's called out is where my text is located.

```
Sub SendMultipleEmails()

    Dim OutApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMail As MailItem
    
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    bodySignature = "Thank you," & vbLf & "Xxx Xxx"
    
    For r = 6 To lr
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        
        With OutMail
        .To = Range("H" & r).Value
        .Subject = Range("E" & r).Value
        bodyHeader = Range("A2").Value
        bodyMain = Range("A3").Value
        .Body = bodyHeader & vbLf & vbLf & bodyMain & vbLf & vbLf & bodySignature
        .Display
    End With
Next r
    
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47924211/paste-excel-range-to-outlook-email-body

Comment: What do you mean by "filter through data" - on what criteria?

Comment: Sample data should be provided as formatted text table, not image.

Comment: Alternative to copy/paste idea is to loop cell range or recordset and build HTML coded body https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36878466/need-to-loop-through-recordset-to-insert-html-table-in-outlook-email-body

Answer (score 0):

You expressed two issues: 1) prevent duplicate emails and 2) build body of email with data. This answer focuses on 1).

Declare a string variable to hold Subject value. Compare to each row, when it is different, send email, when it's same, skip. Reset variable. However, this assumes rows are already ordered by Subject value. If not, do a sort or code will be more complicated and likely involve an array object.

```
For r = 6 To lr
    If s <> Range("H" & r).Value Then
        '... email code ...
    End If
    s = Range("E" & r).Value
Next r
```

An alternative is to open recordset of DISTINCT Subject and Email Addresses and loop.

```
    Const adOpenStatic = 3
    Const adLockOptimistic = 3
    Const adCmdText = &H1
    Dim cn As Object, rs As Object
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    
    cn.Open "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";HDR=Yes';"

    rs.Open "SELECT DISTINCT [Subject], [Email Addresses] FROM [Sheet1$E5:F" & Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).row & "]", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        '... email code referencing recordset fields rs!Subject and rs![Email Addresses]...
        rs.MoveNext 'do not forget this
    Loop
```